# Hazard and Intensity Function Revisited in the light of Hawkes Process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I am looking at the following post in the Statistics Stack Exchange:

- [Difference between hazard function and intensity function?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96034/difference-between-hazard-function-and-intensity-function)

where there was a question about the hazard function in survival analysis and intensity function in Poisson process. The answer was superb and in the end the responder had written (and I rephrase):

> Now, we *can* extend the paradigm to say that the failed system is instantaneously replaced by a brand-new system that begins operating at time $T$, but the analysis now begins anew and the hazard rate $\hat{h}(t)$ for the replacement is $h(t−T)$ etc. In other words, the probability that the replacement is struck dead in $(T,T+\Delta t]$ is $h(0)Δt$, not $h(T)\Delta t$.

Let us hypothetically assume we are extending the survival process and magically the system gets revived. In that case, it appears to me that we need a new hazard rate $\hat{h}(t)$ because we assume independence of events in Poisson process? Suppose we have conditional hazard function instead of pure hazard function so the hazard rate is dependent on the history, then will the natural extension of survival analysis to Poisson process will be a Hawkes process? And how do we prove the new hazard function will be $h(t-T)$?

Comment: interesting, need to have a proper read of the links but in applications (financial at least eg in stochastic time-inhomogeneous default intensities) always have seen hazard rates and intensities used interchangeably/synonymously... interesting stuff for exploration here!

Comment: Just skimmed the question so health warning - not sure I fully understand your question. The highlighted text just seems to posit the introduction of a conditional hazard re-struck at $T$. The Hawkes process seems to impose a specific clustering mechanic, so is perhaps an example of a generalisation, not the most general possible (the above seems quite 'model independent'), but this is just from glancing at definitions and am no expert, so hope you find a good answer!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, from what I understand Hawkes seems to be a special case of marked Poisson process, whatever it is. So, yes, I agree with you that it may not specifically Hawkes, but something close it. But I am extremely new to this area and seeing if I could get some expert answer.